# How to add the Hyper-V Virtual Machine to GNS 3?

Tags: linux, gns3, windows

I am running GNS3 - 2.2.29 in Hyper V Manager, I installed Windows 10 and Kali Linux VM in Hyper V Manager. I want to add windows 10 and Kali Linux host in GNS3 but no host option in GNS3. Could someone help me resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported appliance templates can be download from the following link.

https://gns3.com/marketplace/appliances

For anything else, you can try to create your own template, like Kali. The one for BSD would give you a good starting point.